# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_mailparse.dll' - The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, dll, xampp, ini, php-7

I am using php7 with xampp and windows, 64-bit and try to install mailparse, without success. 
It throws me the next exception:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_mailparse.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

I thought I should:

- update php.ini --> enable mailparse extension
- download mailparse extension dll file and put it in the ext folder in xampp/php

I've tried to find a normal mailparse extension dll for windows and php7 but I didn't find any.

Comment: You can take a look in phpinfo() to see if the module was loaded (it wasn't obviously when looking at your error) and see if your php.ini with new conf is loaded successfully.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the mailparse extension is loaded after **mbstring** extension in php.ini file.

Like this:

```
extension=mbstring
extension=mailparse
```

Comment: I was headbanging trying to work it out, thank you very much.

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: You are my hero too. Thank you, Was driving me nuts!